# How do I get the value of math.random and test it in an if statement?

Tags: javascript

*EDIT* Here is new code but it is still not working for me.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css">
<script src="myjavascript2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Play</button>
<p id="test"></p>



</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var things = ['rock','paper','scissors'];

function myFunction() {

var i = Math.floor(Math.random()*things.length));
document.getElementById("test"+(i+1)).innerHTML=things[i];
}
```

*I added this text so that it would let me post the edit, please ignore this.*

Comment: what's wrong with `if (random == 1)`?

Comment: @njzk2 it didn't work when I tried it for some reason..

Comment: you probably missing the opening `{` after `if(){`, also why create 3 one-time variables of strings? you can do `x.innerHTML="rock";`, aslo closing `}`  of your function

Comment: Always share what you tried so we can determine why it didn't work.

Comment: @njzk2, you should always use '==='.

Comment: @vernak2539 : no. there are `==` and `===` because they mean different things. there is not one better than the other. One should use the operator that is appropriated to the situation. In this case, we know the type of the elements that are being compared, and `===` brings nothing more than `==` does.

Comment: I understand the difference in use, no worries there. It would be fine in this situation, you're right. But it real work situations you don't always know what data you're getting back. '===' just makes it easier for people starting out to see what their mistakes are

Comment: to your edit, you should have 3 html `<p>`s, with id `test1, test2, test3` I believe

Answer (score 6):

You could simply replace your whole code with

```
var things = ['rock','paper','scissors'];
var i = Math.floor((Math.random()*things.length));
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=things[i];
```

This would also let you more easily deal with other operations, like finding a winner.

Comment: Tried your answer but it didn't work

Comment: @DuploW I don't know your whole code but here's a very very short example : http://jsbin.com/daxev/1/edit

Comment: I edited my post so now you can see what I did.

Comment: I also get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null